# I was born with you, you didn't choose me, I didn't choose you, but I will be with you forever till death, you die I love who am I?

Tags: riddle

```
I was born with you,
You didn't choose me,
I didn't choose you, but I will be with you forever till death, 
You die I love 
Who am I?
```

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! At first glance, this question seems a bit "broad." That is to say that there might be many answers that fit your question, yet aren't what you had in mind. You should visit the [help center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for some helpful tips. While you're at it, you can take the [tour](/tour) for an easy badge, too. Good Luck!

Comment: Is **Who am I?** significant of could it be interchanged with **What am I?**

Answer (score 13):

Since it's already [Spooktober](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/spooktober), I'm gonna go with

> [A Skeleton!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dSSt.gif)

I was born with you,
You didn't choose me,
I didn't choose you, but I will be with you forever till death,

> A spooky skeleton is trapped inside your body for your whole life!

You die I love

> Mr Skellington can only be freed from his meaty prison by your death. In addition to calcium, he loves rattling around the town on Halloween, so he is only slightly sad that you had to die.

Answer (score 9):

Could this possibility be...

> **YOUR NAME**? 
>  *I was born with you, you didn't choose me.*
>  You are born with your name, but you tend not to choose it yourself. 
>  *I didn't choose you.*
>  Typically a name doesn't choose you. 
>  *But I will be with you forever 'till death.*
>  You keep your name until you die, until you are dead ("no longer 'you', if that makes sense")
>  **YOUR NAME** fits all of these clues, so I'm pretty sure that it's the answer.

Comment: I was thinking this, but I was stuck on one party. You are born with this answer, as you’ve noted...but the question says that this answer must be born with you, which is a little further from the truth. +1 from me though!!

Comment: I'm thinking that your name stays with you after death as well... look at some tombstones, right? Good guess though, +1.

Comment: My first idea as well, but how does it fit the line "you die I love"?

Comment: I original thought that but i guessed it could not be as our child was not given a name for a few days after being born, therefore in my case this would not work with the first line of the riddle.

Comment: technically you aren't born with your name, it's assigned later, after birth.

Comment: @Chowsen, right... yeah...

Comment: @5202456 yeah, I kinda thought that too... I was given "the answer" before I was born, but my brother was only given "the answer" a week or so after birth.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect it is

> a body part, as Naeem said it here [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/73680/53068)
>  But I'd like to specify and say, it is:
>
>  **The heart.**
>
>  Based on the line "I love" which is - at least in my culture - considered a feeling that "happens" in within the heart.

Comment: nice answer, but can you explain how "_I didn't choose you;_" relates to this? In my mind, your heart doesn't choose you, it physically **can't** choose you.

Answer (score 4):

This definitely seems a little broad and might benefit from a couple more lines, but you could be:

> My Ancestors

I was born with you,

> You've had ancestors since birth (a better fit would see something come into existence with you but this doesn't feel like too much of a stretch)

You didn't choose me,

> Check.

I didn't choose you, but I will be with you forever till death,

> They're your ancestors, whether you like it or not, until you die.

You die I love

> The *afterlife* is a surprisingly common belief which often features re-connecting with long-dead family members who've watched over you.

Comment: this seems like a much better answer than mine.

Answer (score 3):

You could be

> my twin.

I was born with you,

> Twins are born at the same time.

You didn't choose me,
I didn't choose you,

> We don't get to choose our siblings.

but I will be with you forever till death,

> Twins are often inseparable, sometimes even physically.

You die I love

> Not sure about this one. I have some ideas but they're all grim and depressing.

Answer (score 3):

Should the 5th line be "You die I live"?

In which case who am I could be:

> Their soul, as already mentioned, but it would make a lot more sense.

Comment: This would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your

> Body/any body part- fits all the description

Answer (score 2):

Possible answer:

> I first thought "your name", but after some thinking:

I was born with you,

> (Some names are not given until much later, I wasn't named until a week after I was born)

You didn't choose me,

> (This fits, but people can choose to change their names)

I didn't choose you, but I will be with you forever till death,

> (Again, birth names can be changed, but it will still be your birth name)

You die I love

> (not sure on this, don't know how to interpret it)

Who am I?

> My Ideas were either "birth name" or "your mind/conscious"

Answer (score 1):

My guess is:

> A person's or animal's, Soul. (but this will depend on your religion or belief)

I was born with you,

> If you believe that you have a soul, then a common perception is that you a re born with it.

You didn't choose me,

> Some people believe that your body is a vessel for your soul therefore you do not chose which soul it contains.

I didn't choose you, but I will be with you forever till death,

> Again depending on your beliefs your soul is given a body vessel (not chosen by its self)

You die I love

> Some people belive the soul will live for eternity and therefore will be able to carry on loving, also after a person has died loved ones will still morn and love the person/soul

Who am I?

> If your soul makes you the person you are then your Soul will be you, therefore the question starting with, **who** would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Is it...

> The death if ***innocence***.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> Life

Because:

> Life is born with you, you didn't chose it, it leaves when you die, and to live is to love?